# SQL Query - Looping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to output a record per part for each the quantity in the field. E.g. if a part has a qty of 10 then I'd want that part to be listed 10 times, if the qty was 2 then I'd only want the part to be list twice.

Here's a sample of the data:

```
Part    Qty
PSR6621581  17
PSR6620952  13
PSR6620754  11
PSR6621436  11
PSR6621029  9
PSR661712   9
PSR661907   9
PSR662998   8
PSR6620574  7
PSR661781   7
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to expand the rows. For example:

```
with
p as (
  select part, qty, 1 as n from t
 union all
  select part, qty, n + 1
  from p
  where n < qty
)
select part, qty from p
```

Result:

```
 part  qty 
 ----- --- 
 ABC   1   
 DEF   4   
 DEF   4   
 DEF   4   
 DEF   4
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7615aef5378f89e40e027837e0753d26).

Comment: This is really doing something very similar to a loop. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I would agree that in terms of performance a cross join should be way faster than a recursive CTE.

Comment: Although on this tiny dataset is make no difference. And this will absolutely get the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another option. This is using a tally which is the ideal way to handle this type of thing. I keep this view on my system as a crazy fast way of having a tally table.

```
create View [dbo].[cteTally] as

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )
select N from cteTally
GO
```

Now we just create a dummy table with your sample data.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Part varchar(10)
    , Qty int
)
insert @Something
select 'PSR6621581', 17 union all
select 'PSR6620952', 13 union all
select 'PSR6620754', 11 union all
select 'PSR6621436', 11 union all
select 'PSR6621029', 9 union all
select 'PSR661712', 9 union all
select 'PSR661907', 9 union all
select 'PSR662998', 8 union all
select 'PSR6620574', 7 union all
select 'PSR661781', 7
```

Now that the setup is complete the query to produce the output you want is super easy and lightning fast to execute.

```
select s.Part
    , s.Qty
from @Something s
join cteTally t on t.N <= s.Qty
order by s.Part
    , t.N
```

Comment: I will use this approach instead of `Recursive CTE (RBAR)`.Instead of  `View` I will create number table because  single table perform better than `View` . We use `View`  when there are multiple tables join with complicated join and condition.

Comment: @KumarHarsh - A single table will not perform any better or worse than a view. What you are implying is that a view has a performance overhead which simply is not correct. If you look at the execution plan the view produces zero reads and is insanely fast. A persistent numbers table is fine too of course.

Comment: It will be all together a different discussion.You can your self google it "table vs view performance".Yes I can agree that in this example "view produces zero reads".Still I will create number table with Clustered Index.